# Will `ThenInclude()` on a navigation property repeatedly call that property's table?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

Imagine the case where we have the following three objects and we want to get the list of all players, their game settings, and the difficulty property saved within those game settings.

```
public class Player {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public GameSetting Settings { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class GameSetting {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int PlayerId { get; set; }
   public Player Player { get; set; }

   public DifficultyLookupId DifficultyLookupId { get; set; }
   public DifficultyLookup DifficultyLookup { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class DifficultyLookup { 
   ... 
};
```

The `DifficultyLookup` table would consist of constant values, like `{Id: 1, Difficulty: Easy}, {Id: 2, Difficulty: Medium}`.

If we performed an EF Core query like the following:

```
var entities = await _context.Players
   .Include(p => p.Settings)
      .ThenInclude(s => s.DifficultyLookup)
   .ToListAsync();
```

Will this repeatedly hit the `DifficultyLookup` table every time it grabs a Player with a GameSettings and DifficultyLookup entity?

The alternative is that we pull in the `DifficultyLookup` table on its own and then tie the `DifficultyLookup` object to the `GameSetting` object in memory, whereas the alternative (may) be happening with database hits.

Comment: Why don't you check the executed SQL?

Comment: @GertArnold I did, Im just not sure if there is caching of the index lookups going on. If its cached, then its technically not "repeatedly hitting the table" and I'd feel better about the query above.

Comment: It doesn't exactly work like that under the hood, but you could conceive that "yes, tables are repeatedly hit" because it's a join, and joining a 1:M causes the 1 to repeat, so EF will download a large amount of repetitive data and then have to filter it out so it isn't creating multiple ents on the client side. It's not really "repeatedly hitting the table" but it's "repeatedly processing the same data out of the db" and also "downloading repetitive data". You can avoid this with query splitting, but that brings some disadvantages unless more expensive transactional behaviors are used

Comment: @CaiusJard From what I can see `Settings` to `DifficultyLookup` is 1:1 so there shouldn't be multiple lookups or repetitive data returned.

Comment: @NetMage Every player has their own persistent record for `GameSettings`. Those settings have some navigation properties to lookup values like `DifficultyLookup`. So while a given game setting may be unique to a player (1:1), the relationship between `DifficultyLookup` and `GameSetting` is 1:N. For example, some Players with N `GameSettings` all or some with `DifficultyLookup` equal to "Hard" or "Easy".

Comment: That isn't possible given the model shown. Each `GameSetting` has one `DifficultyLookupId` and hence one `DifficultyLookup`. That means `Settings` (which is one `GameSetting`) is 1:1 with `DifficultyLookup`.

Comment: @NetMage Take the `DifficultyLookup` with { ID = 1, Type = HARD }. Can it not be pointed to by `GameSetting` of ID 4? and 5? and 11? and 22? and 44? and 99? That is to say, any given `DifficultyLookup` entity can be pointed to be N `GameSetting` entities.